# How can I get identity-like values in a MERGE INSERT statement

Tags: sql-server, merge

I would like to merge a table `bar` into another table `foo`, and while doing so I have to assign a unique value to a column `messagenr`. This is my attempt to do so (sql-server):

```
MERGE foo AS target 
using bar AS source 
ON target.message LIKE source.message 
WHEN NOT matched BY target THEN 
INSERT (messagenr, 
        language, 
         message) 
VALUES ((SELECT Max(messagenr) 
         FROM   foo) 
       + 1, 
       'EN', 
       source.message);
```

Of course it is not working. I get the very same value for `messagenr` for every new dataset inserted. 
I cannot modify the table structure itself, so I have to work with the structure given.

How can I get a UNIQUE value for `messagenr` in every new dataset in the target table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me set up next example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(messagenr int, language varchar(10), message varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE bar(language varchar(10), message varchar(100));
GO

INSERT INTO foo VALUES 
(1, 'EN', 'M1'),
(2, 'EN', 'M2'),
(3, 'ES', 'M3');

INSERT INTO bar VALUES
('FR', 'M1FR'),
('CA', 'M1CA'),
('DE', 'M1DE');
GO
```

Since you can't increase `messagenr` value inside the transaction, and your MERGE statement only insert values, maybe you could use another approach.

You can use a CTE or a subquery to enumerate the returned rows in this way:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(messagenr) FROM foo) +
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN,
       bar.language, 
       bar.message
FROM   foo
JOIN   bar
ON     bar.message LIKE '%' + foo.message + '%'
```

> ```
> RN | language | message
> :- | :------- | :------
> 4  | FR       | M1FR   
> 5  | CA       | M1CA   
> 6  | DE       | M1DE
> ```

Now you can insert new values using the previous query:

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT (SELECT MAX(messagenr) FROM foo) +
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN,
           bar.language, 
           bar.message
    FROM   foo
    JOIN   bar
    ON     bar.message LIKE '%' + foo.message + '%'
)
INSERT INTO foo (messagenr, language, message)
SELECT RN, 'EN', message
FROM   x;
```

This is the final result:

```
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

> ```
> messagenr | language | message
> --------: | :------- | :------
>         1 | EN       | M1     
>         2 | EN       | M2     
>         3 | ES       | M3     
>         4 | EN       | M1FR   
>         5 | EN       | M1CA   
>         6 | EN       | M1DE
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8a09f0950392dc0eec101a1df35df76b)*

Comment: IT should be SELECT RN, language, message FROM x; to get the correct result. Your final resultset does not meet the requirement because of the constant EN returned, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #foo
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #bar

CREATE TABLE #foo (messagenr INT, language VARCHAR(10), message VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE #bar (language VARCHAR(10), message VARCHAR(100));

INSERT
    #foo
VALUES
    (1, 'EN', 'M1'),
    (2, 'EN', 'M2'),
    (3, 'ES', 'M3');

INSERT
    #bar
VALUES
    ('FR', 'M1FR'),
    ('CA', 'M1CA'),
    ('DE', 'M1DE');

;WITH

x as (
    SELECT messagenr AS messagenr, language, message FROM #foo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, language, message  from #bar
),

y as (
    SELECT
        IIF(messagenr IS NULL, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)), messagenr) AS messagenr, language, message
    from
        x
)

MERGE
    #foo AS TARGET 
using
    y AS SOURCE
ON
    TARGET.message LIKE SOURCE.message 

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (messagenr, language, message)
    VALUES (SOURCE.messagenr, SOURCE.language, SOURCE.message);

SELECT * FROM #foo

messagenr   language   message
----------- ---------- -------
1           EN         M1
2           EN         M2
3           ES         M3
4           FR         M1FR
5           CA         M1CA
6           DE         M1DE
```